# Azure SpatialAnchors in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, azure-spatial-anchors

I've been trying to integrate Azure's SpatialAnchors API into a Xamarin project. Sadly, there's no easy pre-packaged NuGet binary that I can simply add to my project. Microsoft does say that:

> Yes. While we don't provide a Xamarin SDK, we expect developers can use Azure Spatial Anchors in their Xamarin apps by integrating with the Azure Spatial Anchors API.[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/spatial-anchor-faq#technical-faqs)

Does anybody knows anything about this? What API?

I've been trying to import the original library as a JAR but I'm having crashes at runtime caused by functions that Xamarin isn't loading from the JAR. There's also [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors.WinCPP/) NuGet that I landed onto, it doesn't directly expose the API functions. I've been trying to use the content of a Unity C# file to access the content of that NuGet, but that too seems hard to achieve.

Anyone knows how to access the SpatialAnchors API with Xamarin? Is there a self-contained JAR somewhere that has all of the functions?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to bind the Spatial Anchors `.aar` (make sure to set the build action to `LibraryProjectZip`).

- `spatialanchors_java-X.X.X.aar`

You can manually download the latest version (currently 1.0.2) of the .aar from here:

- https://microsoft.bintray.com/AzureSpatialAnchors/com/microsoft/azure/spatialanchors/spatialanchors_java/

Comment: I had previously landed on a AAR file (maybe I should have mentioned it in the OP). For some reason that JAR doesn't expose any of the functions inside of it. The Object browser says that there's nothing inside and the IDE can't find the namespace Com.Microsoft. I opened the AAR with a decompiler and the content seems quite similar to a JAR that I was trying to use. The target API version is 28 and the BuildAction is LibraryProjectZip as indicated in the Xamarin documentaion

Comment: @Axel So you are not looking for the Java aar then? The NDK and JNI aar's are @ https://microsoft.bintray.com/AzureSpatialAnchors/com/microsoft/azure/spatialanchors You might want to start with the actual Java Android sample first (https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/tree/master/Android/Java/app) to understand how things are setup.

Comment: I would use the Java AAR if I could. What I'm saying is that Visual Studio doesn't seem able to read the contents of the AAR given that despite adding those files to an Android Bindings project and setting them as `LibraryProjectZip` as indicated in the docs, the Object browser thinks that there's nothing inside the library and the namespace `Com.Microsoft` isn't visible

Comment: @Axel Pull the JNI aar and make a binding for it.

Comment: Ok so just to be sure, I made a clean project so my previous tests didn't interfere. New project has compile target of API version 28, I added to the new project and to the library, NuGets for ArCore and appcompat to follow some of the dependencies in the sample grade. I added both the Java and JNI to the bindings library and I verified that the build action for both is set to `LibraryProjectZip`. Still, the object browser thinks that the Bindings lib is empty and the namespace `Com.Microsoft` can't be found

Comment: It's not enough to just add the java one, as it depends on the JNI one (and probably more). I'm working towards making this work in Android. Getting close, but still not there quite yet. Check out my repo here: https://github.com/dotMorten/Xamarin.AzureSpatialAnchors